# Downloading from Google Drive with PHP and REST API key

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I would like to force download files from Google Drive on a PC client via this script:

```
<?php 

//Get info about the file from a previous page (its name, type e.g. "rar", and file id which is the $download)
$download = $_GET['download'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$type = $_GET['type'];

//Get json info about the file on drive, used to get its size in bytes
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'.$download.'?key=MYAPIKEY');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$size=$obj->fileSize;

//Download the file
$file = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'.$download.'?key=MYAPIKEY&alt=media';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'.'.$type.'"');    
header('Content-Length: '.$size);
readfile($file);
exit;?>
```

The file gets corrupted when downloaded, any help?
[EDIT] I got it to work, if someone else would like to know how to do this:
add `header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");`
at the beginning of the header lines.

Comment: I accidentely posted the question without actually having written the problem and now I don't know how to edit/delete it. If somemone is still interested: when I download files this way, they get somehow corrupted. Jars, exes or rars, all of them can't be opened.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please See [I've thought better of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) and search for *But there are some other things you can do:*

Comment: It's just the link `edit` or `delete` below your question.

Comment: @help-info.de thanks, these buttons are just too much visible